# Draytek Vigor 2820 incorrectly blocking IP address based on keyword filtering

Tags: firewall, filtering, draytek, vigor

Vigor 2820Vn router (with firmware 3.3.7.8) is blocking IP address URLs with the use of a URL keyword filter. The filter itself is working fine and blocking the URLs based on keyword, but this rule also blocks IP addresses that have nothing to do with the keywords set in the rule.

Here's what the syslog says when the rule is working:

`Aug 24 14:13:12 Vigor: [CSM_UF][Block][Type=KW(G:O=0:3)][@S:R=2:3, 192.168.2.13:14293->http://www.skype.com/:80][HTTP][HLen=20, TLen=365, Flag=AP, Seq=2579681218, Ack=953919792, Win=16473]`

This is correct because the URL filter is set to block addresses that contain `skype`.

Here's how it looks like when the rule incorrectly blocks an IP address:

`Aug 22 18:48:34 Vigor: [CSM_UF][Block][Type=IP][@S:R=2:3, 192.168.2.18:49180->http://216.58.212.46/favicon.ico:80][HTTP][HLen=20, TLen=338, Flag=AP, Seq=3564157813, Ack=1077026064, Win=258]`

This is an IP address that I got using `ping -a google.com`. It has nothing to do with `skype` or other any other keyword.

Here's how this rule is setup:

[image: Vigor 2820 URL blocking rule]

There are no further rules to process. Syslog message clearly indicates this rule is the one blocking access (the `@S:R=2:3` part: `filter set 2, rule 3`).

How should this rule be modified so that it does not block IP address URLs and just block based on the keywords only?

Comment: As I said, there are no further rules. Rule #1 is the router provided "xNetBIOS->DNS" filter. Rule #2 blocks my baby monitor to go out to Internet. It is setup as "if direction is lan->Wan and source ip==192.168.2.17, block immediately".

This #3 rule is set this way because of all the Draytek-provided examples that I found. It works and blocks all the URLs with the keywords I specified. If I switch to "block if no further match" the controls below "Filter" are greyed out and I can't even specify a URL Content filter to start with.

Comment: See http://www.draytek.com/en/faq/faq-security/security.content-security-management-(csm)/how-to-block-facebook-with-url-content-filter-and-dns-filter/ as an example of how draytek recommends setting up the URL filter.